# How to prevent shortcuts from firing when form is not active

Tags: delphi

I open forms inside tabs of a page control. These forms may contain actions with shortcuts. And I want these shortcuts to be fired only when the tab that contain this form is active.

I tried to override form's IsShortCut but it's not called. Form's OnShortCut is not called either.

I would like to avoid putting code on each action to check this.

I'm using Delphi 2010.

Comment: When you say that you have "forms" inside a page control, I suppose that you have TTabSheets inside a TPageControl?

Comment: Well, maybe we are not talking about the same thing after all, because the TForm's OnShortCut is indeed called if one does it as I believed you were doing it...

Comment: Each tabsheet is parent of a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `State` for the action lists on your hidden tabs to `asSuspended`.  Only the action list on your visible tab should have a state of `asNormal`.  That will prevent the shortcut keys from working.  It also prevents those actions from updating, which may or may not be a good thing for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the form's Enabled to false whan you switch away, and True when you switch onto it's tab.  That should disable all the content on the form, including shortcuts.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work, for if a TButton on the TTabSheet is controlled by a TAction, then disabling the TTabSheet (and hence the TButton), will not automatically disable the TAction.

Comment: I'm assuming, from the description, that he's parenting actual TForm descendants onto the tab sheets.  If not, then my answer's probably invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the shortcuts into actions and those actions into one action list per form. Then you can disable the action lists of the forms that are currently not active. (I don't recall the exact TActionList property to set or method to call or activating/deactivating it, but it is there.)